Why are these RGB grounds connected to the signals?
This is part of the schematics from an old arcade cabinet. The RGB signals all have distinctive grounds that seem connected directly to the signals cable. How is it possible? There is a video ground pin at 16b that is connected to the monitor alone.

Source: Manuale dell' operatore - Sidam p.8
——-
I checked the cables. They are intertwined to the R G B cables but not connected to any ground

Looks like underdamped ringing ?

@SteveSh means what ?

Sarcasm.  The attempt to show the ground wire wrapped around the signal reminds me of ringing on a edge..

In any case, I'm not sure how effective they are at shielding.  A wire, connected on one end, even if that's to ground, can very easily become an antenna.

I'm not sure if the spirals around the signal lines are meant to be twisted pairs or coaxial, but since they are only connected to one side of the connector/cable, this would be to prevent cross talk on other signal lines and/or EMI compliance.

The RGB grounds are not connected to signals. That's a schematic representation of ground shielded/pairef signal, such as how the connector pins connect to coaxial cable, a common cabling for video signals inside devices.


Figure 1. Double-click for full-size view.

The grounds are not connected to the RGB lines. Those are drafting symbols indicating ground screens wrapped around the signal wires.
They are connected only at the end shown on the wiring diagram. (There are no terminals to accept the screens on the 6-pin connector on the right hand side.)
The screens will usually continue to as close as practical to the signal termination (and then be cut off) so as to provide maximum shielding from interference. To reduce clutter the drawing doesn't show the shielding all the way along the wires.
Grounding shields at one end only is common in audio and industrial control systems to prevent ground loops which can pick up interference (heard as mains hum in audio circuits). They might use the same technique here to avoid video channel interference.


I'm not sure if I should read this purely as interpreting the schematic given (if so, please include the latter part where the shields are(n't) shown?), or as general advice/recommendation; if the latter, you should know it's actively harmful advice.

Sorry, @TimWilliams, but I don't understand your comment. Can you clarfiy - especially the last few words. The OP says, "There is a video ground pin at 16b that is connected to the monitor alone" so it's not as though there is no ground reference between the two circuits.

@Transistor Generally the coax grounds would be connected on both ends, as the high speed video signal return currents would prefer to return in the shield, you rarely want them to return via some other route. But, the other end is not visible so we don't know if they are connected or not - but that wasn't asked either.

@TimWilliams, OK. I'm not a high-speed man. Mostly audio and industrial control. My recollection of VGA, etc., was as described. It may be faulty! It sounds like you have better info for an answer.

PDF with entire schematics https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LnaPFfsXgq7ZFdoSCdYB5SBWBxf2pQea/view?usp=drivesdk

@TimWilliams, there's no termination for the screens on the full schematic. Maybe that's why it broke. d:^)

@Transistor I have a strong understanding of EMC topics, including shielding, but not of how it's applied (or not) in the present case.  If I wrote such an answer, it would be knowingly false. You wrote the 2nd and 4th points, apparently without full schematics to hand -- as a reader, with no further information to hand, I can only conclude these are unfounded assumptions, likely incorrect, and worth downvoting as such. If you possess information supporting these points, you should include that in the answer, so that readers can review and confirm them.

@Transistor It’s not broken. I am trying to make an adapter for jamma and was wondering what should I do with those 3 ground pins.
